# jQuery Ajax request in Grails

Tags: ajax, jquery, grails

How to use jQuery to make Ajax request in Grails pages?

How to setup a URL hitting a method on Grails Controller? Let's say controller:'airport', action:'getJson' and input to the action is 'iata'.

I am able to set static url as `http://localhost:8080/trip/airport/getJson` but not able to figure out how to pass input for iata specifically.

I am fairly new to Grails and following IBM's 'Mastering the Grails' tutorial series. Do suggest me some good tutorial on using jQuery with Grails.

Comment: What do you mean with 'input to the action'? id? a parameter value? raw post body? raw query?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov It's parameter to the controller method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use the $.ajax method in jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url:"${g.createLink(controller:'airport',action:'getJson')}",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        iata: '.............',
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data)
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {
        alert(error)
    },
    complete: function() {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/trip/airport/getJson',
  data: {paramName: 'iata'}
});
```

use your parameter name, that you're expecting in action, intead of `paramName`, that i've used.

Comment: Is it the best way to use link like /trip/airport... instead of g.createLink?

Comment: it's only way for `.js` file, for gsp `g.createLink` is preferred

Comment: But js from gsp wouldn't be in browser's cache. What is preferred? :)

Comment: you can use js, but configure base path from gsp (through `window.myAppPath = '${g.createLink(uri: '/')}`)

Comment: Thanks! Not sure, that using of global variables is the best way, but now I know, how to use grails tags in js.