# Grails: How to display data from datasource based on selection in GSP form

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

I have a pulldown menu generated from a MySQL dataSource.

```
 <g:select onchange="selected()"  id="name" name="name" from="${listOfNames()}" noSelection="['':'--']"/>
```

this populates the menu with one column from my table

Now based on the selection I want to display additional columns from the same table as text on the gsp form.

so user selects Name1 from dropdown. I display underneath the dropdown menu

Name1. age 21. degree yes.

I have an action inside my controller called allDetails that queries all values associate with a name and returns it a string. But I am not sure how to pass it parameters

```
"${remoteFunction(action:'allDetails', params: \'name=\' params.name')}
```

What is the best way to do this. run a JavaScript  remote function inside selected() or a gsp tag that calls the action somehow? how to then display the returned string? Change the innerHTML?

tried http://www.grails.org/AJAX-Driven+SELECTs+in+GSP

Comment: 1. how to pass value - Where are you issuing the remoteFunction call from and what is params.name?
2. Best way - Don't know if it is the best way or not but, you could directly call the remoteFunction on change. e.g., in the [remoteFunction docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html)
3. remoteFunction has an optional parameter 'update'. I believe you could make use of that to update the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use [`remoteFunction`](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html) or [other core Grails tags](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#ajax), because its text is fully generated during page rendering, and you only know the selected name during Javascript executing in `onchange`.

So use [jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431049/jquery-ajax-request-in-grails) (unless you switched to a different Javascript plugin).

And I suggest that you select not a name, but an `id` of that person, like in a second [g:select](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Tags/select.html) example.